# JobScheduler setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY) not working

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

The following code never runs. The job is scheduled successfully however it is never actually executed. I've even set an overriding deadline of 1m10s. The device is connected to WiFi at all times and even after 5 hours of wait, I never see it launched. What am I doing wrong?

```
  int REFRESH_JOB_ID = 13;
  jobScheduler.cancel(REFRESH_JOB_ID);

  // Requires WiFi / Edge / 3G
  JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(REFRESH_JOB_ID, componentName).
      setMinimumLatency(1 * 60 * 1000).
      setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY).
      setRequiresCharging(false).
      setRequiresDeviceIdle(false).
      setPersisted(true).
      setOverrideDeadline((1 * 60 * 1000) + (10*1000)).
      build();

  int errorCode = 0;
  if ((errorCode = jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo)) > 0) {
    Log.i("Auto Scheduler", "... job has been scheduled: " + errorCode);
  } else {
    Log.e("Auto Scheduler", "... job FAILED to schedule: " + errorCode);
  }
```

Comment: Perhaps your problem lies in the job service identified by `componentName`. Check LogCat at your designated time and see if there are any messages related to trying to execute the job.

Comment: Thank you, that was it :) I had copy pasted that from another service and forgot to change the actual class that gets launched! Doh.

Comment: @strangetimes, what is your device manufacturer, operating system, skin system?

Answer (score 0):

Try after setting  `setMinimumLatency(15*60*1000)`

As 15 minutes is the minimum (Perhaps.)