# JobScheduler Job gets cancelled after the process being killed

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

This is how I set up my job:

```
val builder = JobInfo.Builder(1, ComponentName(this, 
PullDataJob::class.java))
            .setPeriodic(1000L * 60 * 60) // one hour
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
            .setPersisted(true)
jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build())
```

My test procedure:

1. Open my app
2. Use `adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler` to get active jobs list. My job can be seen in the list.
3. Kill the process by swiping my app from the Recent list.
4. Use the same command and find out that my job is gone.
5. `jobScheduler.allPendingJobs.size` becomes 0.
6. Reopen my app.
7. My job still does not exist in the active job list unless I manually schedule it again (Even though I use `setPersisted(true)`).

My test environment:

Hydrogen OS, Android 7.1.1, targetSdkVersion: 26.

Is that expected behavior? What should I do if I want the job to run periodically even if the app gets killed?

Comment: Yes, it is desired behavior. Action number 3) gives the user the power to permanently stop an app from using CPU.

Comment: Try out this link may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38410309/jobscheduler-setrequirednetworktypejobinfo-network-type-any-not-working

Comment: @AmjadKhan How does this two questions related to each other...

Comment: @Henry So what is the recommended way to send notifications to user?

Comment: It still happens with android-P; Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I've identified the problem. There is an optimization option that cancels all my jobs when my app gets closed.

It's inside "Settings" - "Battery" - "Battery Optimization" - "Advanced Optimization". (My system language is not English so it's an approximate translation)

Comment: Didn't work for me :( I'm in Android O - After process is killed my jobs disappear

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Is there anyone, who is able to resolve this issue? I have tried for disable no restriction on background data, no battery optimatization and enabled autostart feature in redmi. But job scheduler is not working after app killed by swiping in recent task list.